# Get error: unexpected keyword argument 'random_state' when using TomekLinks

Tags: python, data-processing, imbalanced-data

My code is:

```
  undersample = TomekLinks(sampling_strategy='majority', n_jobs= -1,  random_state = 42)
  X_tl, y_tl = undersample.fit_resample(X, y)
```

When I run it, I get this error:

```
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'random_state'
```

My package version is:

```
 imbalanced-learn==0.9.0
```

although in the [documentation](http://glemaitre.github.io/imbalanced-learn/generated/imblearn.under_sampling.TomekLinks.html) this parameter exists:

> random_state : int, RandomState instance or None, optional
> (default=None)

when I check the constructor in `_tomek_links.py`, I don't see the random state field:

```
  @_deprecate_positional_args
    def __init__(self, *, sampling_strategy="auto", n_jobs=None):
        super().__init__(sampling_strategy=sampling_strategy)
        self.n_jobs = n_jobs
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, you're looking at the wrong documentation. That one is for version `0.3.0-dev`, so I checked: https://imbalanced-learn.org/stable/references/generated/imblearn.under_sampling.TomekLinks.html -- this parameter has been deprecated in a newer version `0.9.0`.

Also as the documentation goes, seems you have to specify it in `make_classification` function as below:

```py
X, y = make_classification(n_classes=2, class_sep=2,
                           weights=[0.1, 0.9], 
                           n_informative=3, n_redundant=1, 
                           flip_y=0, n_features=20, 
                           n_clusters_per_class=1, 
                           n_samples=1000, random_state=10
                          )
```